# Using Parameters in PowerBI in DAX for creating new measures

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am fairly new to PowerBI and have a situation at hand.
I have a column on which I have to create two parameters and compare the values against each other.

Example:

```
Animal:    Food:      Capacity:
Dog        Milk       10
Dog        Bone       26
Cat        Milk       20
Cat        Bone       8
Bird       Grain      6
Bird       Water      9
```

When I select Parameter1 as Dog and Parameter2 as Cat, I should get something like this:

```
Food:    CalcMeasureDog  CalcMeasureCat<br>
Milk         10                  20
Bone         26                  8
```

Is this something we can achieve in PowerBI? 
Main challenge is to use the Parameters in the calculation to do the below:

```
CalcMeasureDog=IF(Animal=Parameter1,Capacity,0)
CalcMeasureCat=IF(Animal=Parameter2,Capacity,0)
```

Also, I don't really want to show the animal column on the report on which i have the parameters created.

Appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a measure for all animals:

```
Total Capacity = SUM(Table[Capacity])
```

where Table is the name of your table.

Then, create measures for specific animals:

```
Dog Capacity = CALCULATE( [Total Capacity], Table[Animal] = "Dog")

Cat Capacity = CALCULATE( [Total Capacity], Table[Animal] = "Cat")
```

If you drop these measures into a matrix with food on the rows, you should get your desired result.

Comment: Thank you, Rado. That really helped. I had to make a slight variation to the solution though to add a dynamic filter in the filter condition, since i need the value to change with a parameter. Cat Capacity = CALCULATE( [Total Capacity], FILTER(Table,Table[Animal]=[Animal Parameter])) . Worked like a gem then. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to just put them all in a matrix visual with `Food` on the rows, `Animal` on the columns, and `SUM(Table[Capacity])` as the values and use a single slicer for both parameters:

[image: Slicer and Matrix]

I'm not sure how well this works for your particular report as I don't quite understand what you meant by

> I don't really want to show the animal column on the report on which i have the parameters created.

Comment: Thank you, Alexis. I got to learn something about Matrix in PowerBI today coz of your answer. One of the things with the requirement is they want one column to be fixed with a certain value (say dog) and then have an animal to compare it against. This animal will need to be selected through a filter/parameter.